# Complex query filtering of object arrays in MongoDb (C# Driver)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Let's say I have this document.

```
"Id" : "lot1",
"Fruits" : [
       [{ "Id": "fruit1", "Name": "apple"}, { "Id": "fruit2", "Name": "carrot"}]
       [{ "Id": "fruit3", "Name": "banana"}]
     ]
```

**Q:** How can I query the Fruits array by a list of fruits names ?

I have tried like this:

```
var fruitNames = new List<string>(){ "apple", "banana" };
var builder = Builders<Lot>.Filter;
var filter = builder.AnyIn(l => l.Fruits.Select(f => f.Name), fruitNames); //TAKE 1
var filter = builder.Where(l => l.Fruits.Select(f => f.Name).Any(f => fruitNames.Contains(f)));//TAKE 2
var filter = builder.AnyIn("Fruits.Name", fruitNames );//TAKE 3
var results = mongoContext.Lots.Find(filter).ToList();
```

I have tried this in 3 different ways with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this? It is a little hack but i am pretty sure it will work:

```
var filter= Builders<Lot>.Filter.ElemMatch(y => y.fruits, x => fruitNames.Contains(x.name));
```

Comment: If the current "Fruits" array would be an singular object, how would the query modify ?

var filter = Builder<Lot>.In(l => l.Fruits.Name, fruitNames); // doesn't work

Comment: did you sort it out or you still need help @Misi?